# define hotkeys minimize Windows on the sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to create a hotkey to minimize and restore the sublime but even the Main.sublime-menu is undefined !

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+w"], "command": "toggle_minimize_restore_window"
}
```

I apologize if there is a mistake in the text, because my English is not good too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggling the state of Sublime Text windows is not something that is possible to do at the moment - you can not maximize, minimize, restore, or resize a Sublime Text window using Sublime Text commands. There have been feature requests for this but you can not do it at present.

If you are using Linux, you might be able to achieve this functionality by writing a shell script which uses `wmctrl` to achieve that functionality and then assign the script to a global hotkey. No doubt there are ways of doing the same thing with OS X and Windows but I do not know what the equivalents would be.

Comment: Do we know if this answer is still true, now with Sublime 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the built-in window's keystrokes in order to minimize and maximize.

> windows key + down (arrow) = minimize the window.
>
> windows key + up (arrow) = maximize the window.

You can try with Mac with Command.

If you want to minimize for a customized position, you can detach the tab adjust it as you wish. Next time you minimize the window, it will appear in this last position you set.